Hosting dedicated Terraria server on Debian server, can see it on my pc but can't connect
I am new to hosting a Terraria 1.4.4.9 server and decided to go for the wonderfully complicated route of trying to set it up on my personal server. The server is just my old pc running Debian 12. Everything seems ok at first, when I run the server I am able to launch the world and when it's launched and I click on "join by IP" in the multiplayer tab on my gaming pc I can see the name of the world and that it's on 127.0.0.1, however when I try to join I get stuck on the connecting to world screen. I am running firewall-cmd and have checked to make sure that my port 7777/TCP is open and it is so I'm not sure what else to do. Any advice would be appreciated.

Unless you are launching terraria on the same machine you're hosting the server on (which doesn't seem like that's the case), the server's IP will never be 127.0.0.1, as that will always be the adress of the current computer.
On debian, you may use the ip a command to learn the local IP address of your server, most likely in the form 192.168.x.x, and use that adress to connect to it from the same local network.
